# CALL TRANSACTION MR11 does not fill error table

Tags: error-handling, ui-automation, abap, sap-erp

For automation, I do

```
CALL TRANSACTION 'MR11' USING BDCDATA
UPDATE 'S'
MODE 'N'
MESSAGES INTO P_MESSTAB
```

When there is some problem on the selection screen of MR11, the error messages are written into P_MESSTAB.

But when errors occur later in the processing, MR11 shows an error protocol without using the MESSAGE command. In this case, the error messages are not written into P_MESSTAB so the caller has no clue what went wrong.

Any idea how the caller can get the error messages of the error protocol of MR11?

Comment: There's an UPDATE parameter when you 'CALL TRANSACTION ... ', what value are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There is a BAPI available for transaction MR11.

==> BAPI_GRIRDOC_CREATEMULTIPLE

Messages are available in the Return-Parameter-Table. The BAPI is well documented.  I would recommend always use BAPI's instead of CALL TRANSACTION, if available.

Comment: This BAPI seems to be not active by defauit. In EHP7 for ECC 6.0, It checks whether enhancement "Government Procurement JFMIP" is switched on. If not, it returns without doing anything.

Comment: Yes, it is related to Business Function JFMIP_MM_01. You can activate it in transaction SFW5. Sometimes additional functionality is delivered as business functions. Of course you need to check it has no other impact!